# How does a malicious user connect to a private network?

Tags: network, firewalls

I have followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-digitalocean-private-networking-on-existing-droplets) for setting up a couple of servers to have private networking.  It ends by saying "It is important to secure your private networking interface the same way you would secure a public interface.".  Is this securing the private network if a node within it becomes compromised?  I was under the impression a third party could not access a private network from outside the network.

Comment: You may want to google the phrase "defense in depth" for some background.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they mean that at the endpoints of the communication, you need to practice good security.  The private network only protects data in transit, not at the end-points.

All the computers that connect to the private network need to be secured using standard operating systems security tools.